# Get selected value from a select variable in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I know the following thing

```
 var selectedVal = $('#select option:selected').attr('value');
```

But, i want to do something like

```
  var combo=$('#select');     
  var selectedVal = $(combo + 'option:selected').attr('value');
```

any clue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use comma not + to get descendant. Also note .val() you don't need to use .attr

```
  var combo=$('#select');     
  var selectedVal = $(combo, 'option:selected').val();
  //                       ^^
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wLf6G/2/)

Answer (score 4):

You should be using :

```
var selectedVal = $(combo).find('option:selected').attr('value');
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way is no need of variables, directly with selectors or selector's ID using # and `val()` method of jQuery

```
var selectedVal = $('#select').find('option:selected').val();
```

Or

```
var selectedVal = $('#select','option:selected').val();
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use change function to get selected value

```
$("#select").change(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wLf6G/3/)

Comment: I've edited you answer, added your code from the fiddle and made it a clickable link. Next time you write an answer don't just link a fiddle.

Comment: actually i am answering first time here! can u please tell me how to write answer here...